# Estoy intentando integrar mercado pago a ionic y me da ERROR en el SSL

Tags: ionic, mercadopago, ssl

Estoy intentando integrar mercado pago a ionic y me da ERROR en el SSL
Este es el error que me muestra:

```
Error: your payment cannot be processed because the website contains credit crad data and is not usig a secure connection.SSL
 certificate is required to operate.
       at o (mercadopago.js:1)
       at n (mercadopago.js:1)
       at mercadopago.js:1
       at mercadopago.js:1
       at mercadopago.js:1
       at Object.l.getPaymentMethod (mercadopago.js:1)
       at u (mercadopago.js:1)
       at mercadopago.js:1
       at mercadopago.js:1
       at Object.l.getPaymentMethod (mercadopago.js:1)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: la información es insuficiente para poder saber que te pasa.
considera agregar el código de ejemplo y los errores.

Comment: El error es medio autoexplicativo. Tu sitio funciona sobre HTTPS? Seguramente no lo está haciendo (no nos lo indicas) y mercadopago está **exigiendo** que así sea porque es inseguro recibir datos del cliente (los de la TC) en una página HTTP sin más. Si es un entorno de prueba, puedes usar un certificado autofirmado e igual correr tu sitio sobre HTTPS